# How to add **Note in Product Custom Option Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I want to add some description below to the each product custom option, Is there any way?

Plese find below product screenshot:

[image]

Comment: let me know whether you would like to save after add to cart?

Comment: hi ashish please let me know is it infough for you https://prnt.sc/lsya8j please confirm so that i will post my answer  how to add

Comment: hi ashish please confirm me. that note will display only for configurable products

Comment: This is exactly that i want, this is for specific custom option? also, this is for specific product and specific custom option.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/lsya8j custom block will display after the custom options for the configurable product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. app/code/Magently/Ajax/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.options.wrapper">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="magently.ajax.info" template="Magently_Ajax::info.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> 2. app/code/Magently/Ajax/view/frontend/templates/info.phtml

```
<div>Note: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</div>
 <?php 
      //Get product attribute value
      $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
      echo $product->getSku();
 ?>
```